# Mapping MAC to Vendor, where is the list?

Tags: networking, mac-address, nmap, vendor

I have seen tools and website like nmap which map a given mac address to a matching vendor, but my question is:

Where can I retrieve this list from? I'm looking for an authoritative, always up-to-date copy from the same source which takes care of maintaining the list.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

IEEE maintains these lists:

[MA-L (24 bit)](https://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt) [(CSV)](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.csv)

[MA-M (28 bit)](https://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui28/mam.txt) [(CSV)](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui28/mam.csv)

[MA-S (36 Bit)](https://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui36/oui36.txt) [(CSV)](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui36/oui36.csv)

Here is the [IEEE registration authority page](https://standards.ieee.org/products-programs/regauth/). I hope this helps.